# primefaces uploader , upload more than one file issue

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using jsf2 with primefaces 3.5.

I added file upload component to my website as follow :

```
<p:panel toggleable="true" id="panel2"><p:fileUpload value="#{MyBeanObj.fileObj}"  mode="simple" required="true" /></p:panel>
```

It works fine if i upload file twice "without navigate to other page" , but if i try to upload for the third time i got this exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mytomcatFolder/temp/upload__430dc599_13fcd9cf9c3__7fff_00000121.tmp (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:719)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor469.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor469.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doGetState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:231)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.getState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:192)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.getState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:207)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:177)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:143)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.hedma.common.utils.servlets.SiteHitCounter.doFilter(SiteHitCounter.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My managedbean is viewscoped managebean ... and the uploading file code is :

```
public void addNewPhoto(){


    try{


    if(file!=null){
        boolean issuccess=false;
        String fileName = file.getFileName().replaceAll("\\s+", "");


        destination = "/images/";
     createDestination(destination);
     newPhoto.setPhotoPat(fileName);


     // Do what you want with the file       
     try {

     copyFile(fileName, file.getInputstream());


     } 
     catch (Exception e) {

     //loging ...
      } 


    newPhoto=null;
    newPhoto=new ProductPhotosDto();






}

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
      try {



      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination+ fileName));

      int read = 0;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

      while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
      out.write(bytes, 0, read);
      }

      in.close();
      out.flush();
      out.close();

      //system.out.println("New file created!");
     } catch (IOException e) {
        //log
      }
      }
```

How can i get rid of this exception ?

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by adding "file=null" after uploading the file and make return string to the same page! So my backing bean become like that :

```
public String addNewPhoto(){


try{


if(file!=null){
    boolean issuccess=false;
    String fileName = file.getFileName().replaceAll("\\s+", "");


    destination = "/images/";
 createDestination(destination);
 newPhoto.setPhotoPat(fileName);


 // Do what you want with the file       
 try {

 copyFile(fileName, file.getInputstream());


 } 
 catch (Exception e) {

 //loging ...
  } 


newPhoto=null;
newPhoto=new ProductPhotosDto();

file=null;


return "uploadPage.jsf";

}
```

Hope this help anybody .. thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue, but mine happens just sometimes/randomly. I'll try to use your solution and come back with feedback.

Comment: It didn't seem to make any difference. I'll try with PF 4.0, because the file upload was completely rewritten.

Comment: Thanks for updating me :) .. can you update me if it solved with you , as of now it happens with me randomly

Comment: You're welcome. I've found and want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18424898/1385906 It actually makes a lot of sense, so I'll try to see.