# File not found exception for temporary files

Tags: java, spring, jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I'm building java app (Spring & JSF & PrimeFaces). I upload a file to the server, however, if I click "next" button right after the file upload ends, I get this error:

```
Aug 24, 2013 8:12:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/codekata] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e1s3'] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\upload__6f71235a_140b1bdd246__8000_00000011.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:709)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

If I wait a couple of seconds, all works fine.
I assume that the upload file needs to have time to copy itself to the temporary folder, does anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem. I use Tomcat 7.

Here is my download method:

```
public StreamedContent getDownloadFile()
    {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(selectedBook.getBookText().getText().getBytes());
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream, "text/plain", selectedBook.getTitle() + ".txt", BookBean.encoding);
    }
```

Thanks,
Luke.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like that you're storing the `UploadedFile` instance as a property of a class which is by itself `Serializable`. This is not right. You should be grabbing the uploaded file content **immediately** in the `<p:fileUpload handleFileUpload>` file upload listener method (or the submit button in case you are using `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">`). Store it at a more permanent location. E.g. the local disk file system, or the database, or maybe even as a `byte[]` bean property. And then pass the local disk file system filename, or database PK, or the `byte[]` around instead in order to have a handle to download the file back.

Summarized, just make sure that your `Serializable` backing bean is completely free of a `UploadedFile` property and this problem shall disappear.

Comment: Are you suggesting to put the uploaded file in to @SessionScoped bean Controller? Also from the above code you can see that the file is created from text, which is passed to it, it is not a member of the Serializable bean, although the method is implemented in a Serializable bean. In the case of upload, you are right that UploadedFile is a member of Serializable bean. See also my above comment to the previous answer.

Comment: Under the covers, the `UploadedFile` instance is stored in memory and/or temporary storage location. It's not a permanently reusable hook to the uploaded file content. It's your responsibility to grab its contents **as soon as possible** and store it in a more permanent location. You can in turn safely store its filename as `String`, or its DB PK as `Number`, or its content as `byte[]` in a session scoped bean. Those things are serializable.

Comment: I get the point, I will implement the changes and get back with result later.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code, the first thing that comes to mind would be to synchronize threads, so that your button action will wait for the upload process to finish.

EDIT: From the way you're describing it, your action is apparently being called too soon, so that the file hasn't yet been properly written.

One way to get around this would be to check if the file exists:

```
File file = new File(<path_to_tmp_file>);
  if(file.exists()){
    //Download file
  }
```

Comment: but the file upload is finished, at least on the user interface, when the file upload is finished, the "next" button is enabled. I press next and get the above given error if I don't wait a couple of seconds. Because the logic which sits behind the next uses the file.

Comment: Maybe you could keep somewhere as an object your file only temporarily, especially if you read it immediately you could pass it as a parameter maybe. What is ceertain is that you would have fewer problems if you stored this file in a database, but I guess it doesn't fit to your requirement. That said where is stored your file ? somewhere outside the application files, I guess ?

Comment: User upload the file (text file), I read the text. Then I produce some new text from the given text, next I create a file with new text, and then the user download the file. The file is created immediately before user download it, so it has not much time to I assume to be copied to temp from the point its created.

Comment: Did you try adding my answer to your code? It may help, or it may not, but we won't know for sure until you do.

Comment: What I did, I set up threshold on the filter in web.xml, however it is only a temporary solution. Now all works fine for files that are blow the threshold. I don't really know how to check if the file exists in temp location, because as you can see from the given upload method, I give it text, then it's transformed into InputStream and this is what I is send to user.

Comment: You see, your InputStream takes a `byte[]` as constructor argument, so you could try checking that buffer for its length and/or contents before passing it to the constructor.

Comment: I got the point here, and I understand that this approach is also a good one, however in my current system, BalusC solution seems to be simpler.

Comment: yeah well, he usually knows stuff :P